# Annunity calculation before and after tax

Tags: php, math, formula, finance

I'm doing a annunity calculation through my script:

```
    $calculation= 
            ( 400000 * 0.02458/( 1- pow( 1+(0.02458) , -84) ) ) ;

    return round($calculation,2);
```

This will return me the payment per. month of the loan (4.337,76), over a period of 84 months.

Now, what i would like to know is what the payment per. month will be after a deduction of 33% tax on the interest rate. In the previous example `(4.337,76)` the result will be `4.236,91`.

Etc. Loan before tax:

```
    Month       Interest        Payment         Total
    0           815,87          3.561,88        4.377,76
    1           807,12          3.570,64        4.377,76
    2           798,34          3.579,42        4.377,76
```

Loan after tax:

```
    Month       Interest        Payment         Total
    0           546,63          3.561,88        4.108,52
    1           540,77          3.570,64        4.111,41
    2           534,89          3.579,42        4.114,30
```

As you can see, the deduction is made to the interest, which is deducted by the 33%. ( Month 1: (851,86*0.67) = 546,63

I'm certain that there is a fancy method of doing this in the annunity calculation, without having to calculate a full table, fetching every single interest and doing the calculation there. I JUST cant find it!

Looking forward to great answers

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, this is more math/algebra than anything.

Comment: True. But it is a tad related to the programming since most programs like Excel or Wolfram offers to calculate this for you through tabels. Perhaps Php has a unknown method for the same. I'm sorry if the question is a misfit for StackOverflow

Comment: nope. php has no financial functions, just basic math. there's probably fin libs available somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want to correlate for taxes in the interest rate right? You only have to say:

```
R-real = R-nom * (1-T)
```

where `R-real` is interest after taxes, `R-nom` before taxes and `T = taxes`.

I've pasted a quick Excel example as image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqyXE.png

I hope this makes sense.